# Button Support for 3dConnexion SpaceMouse Pro

Tags: customization, shortcut, 3d-mouse

I was able to adjust the NDOF settings to get my 3d mouse to work for navigation and I was also able to map the buttons for views, menu, and fit. The problem now is the remaining buttons that show no connectivity. Four of which I think should be working automatically (<kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>),  but since Blender disables the use of settings from 3dConnection Preferences this leaves the coding in blender to handle these functions. Anyone have any ideas on how to?